# Error when inserting a record into MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have val `MyDate` in my C# program that contain **today-date** or **null**.

I have date field in my access 2007 -  `TdateOpen`

I try to insert to the database like this:

```
SQL = "insert into MyCount(TdateOpen) values ('" + MyDate +"')";
```

and I get this error:

```
Data type mismatch in criteria expression
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: I wonder how can you have a DateTime variable whose value is null in C#.

Comment: like this i can..... public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

Coz in your SQL statement you are entering date as String . Instead of String it should be a date/date format.
Try to surround by # .

Comment: There is an additional problem in that null cannot have delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure that the date is in US order (mm/dd/yyyy) or ANSI/ISO order, whether you use dash or slash is not important, ANSI/ISO is to be preferred.

Then as, Madhu CM said, the delimiter for dates in Access is hash (#), however, your date can be null and null cannot be delimited, so you will either have to add the delimiter to a date string, if a date is returned, or use two sql statements, one for null and one for date.

Comment: The requirement is not US order or ANSI/ISO order, but US order or an unambiguous format. ISO format is once such unambiguous format.

Answer (score 0):

You could SQL parameters instead of dynamically embedding the date value into the statement.

```
SQL = "insert into MyCount(TdateOpen) values (?)";
var parameter = yourCommand.CreateParameter();
parameter.Value = yourDateTime;
yourCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

(DISCLAIMER: The code was not compiled nor tested, but it should give you a hint)