# VBA SQL Access DB Query Date Statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010, ado, adodb

I'm using VBA to connect to a Access Database. Having some problems when running date criteria for a query.

I have a cell (C7) with a date in it, and I want to query results based on that date, below is my code:

```vb
    'Query1 Populate
    query = "SELECT * FROM " & TABLE & " WHERE ReportRunDate = " & _
            Chr(35) & Format(Sheet1.Range("C7").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") & Chr(35)
    MsgBox query
    Set Rs1 = Conn1.Execute(query)
    MsgBox Rs1.RecordCount
```

No Errors are given, but no results are given, if I take the output from the variable query and run it directly into access the results are there. What might be happening?

Comment: What's the field type for `ReportRunDate` ?

Comment: Access stores dates just as Excel: as doubles. Consider using double values to filter your data. Check my answer below

Comment: @TimWilliams Data type is Date/Time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a different date format:

```vb
    'Query1 Populate
    query = "SELECT * FROM " & TABLE & " WHERE ReportRunDate = #" & _
            Format(Sheet1.Range("C7").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
    MsgBox query
    Set Rs1 = Conn1.Execute(query)
    MsgBox Rs1.EOF
```

Comment: In Access (and Excel), dates and times are sensitive to Windows Regional Configuration. Your answer may work in this case, but it may not work with other regional configurations.

Comment: I'm no Access expert - I based my answer in part off https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724015/error-when-inserting-a-record-into-ms-access/3725449#3725449 and http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html which basically recommended using either "US" format or any format which is *unambiguous*.  The second link notes that regional settings only apply when *entering* data. Not arguing against your approach...

Comment: I brought the regional format issue to attention because it has caused me lots of tears and suffering in the past (that was one of the main reasons I stopped using Access).. The only (almost) bulletproof solution I found was relying on double values

Answer (score 2):

I'd convert the date value to a double value to avoid any formatting issues. Remember: MS Office programs (Excel & Access, for example) use doubles to store dates and times.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM " & TABLE & " WHERE ReportRunDate = " & _
        CDbl(Sheet1.Range("C2").Value)
```

I've used this strategy many times and it has worked for me.