SQL Syntax problem out of ideas as to cause of problem
I am having some problems with an Access query.  What I am looking to do is to perform a query where the controls are read, consisting of a combo box and two text boxes, the SQL query is formulated, and then exporting to a csv file.  The first example formulates the SQL string, and uses the DoCmd.RunSQL statement, and it is causing an error.
Here is my code to date:
Option Explicit
    
    
Private Sub Cmd_SaveToFile_Click()
    
    'read combo box and two text boxes into variables
    Dim Str_SQL As String
    Dim str_Keyword As String
    Dim Str_StartDate As String
    Dim str_EndDate As String
    Dim null_SetUp As Boolean
            
    null_SetUp = False
    'set focus to Cmb_Keyword so we can read it
    Cmb_Keyword.SetFocus
    If Cmb_Keyword.Text = "" Then
        null_SetUp = True
    Else
        str_Keyword = Cmb_Keyword.Text
    End If
            
    'set focus to StartDate so we can read it
    Txt_StartDate.SetFocus
    If Txt_StartDate.Text = "" Then
        null_SetUp = True
    Else
        Str_StartDate = Txt_StartDate
    End If
            
    'Set focus to EndDate so we can read it
    Txt_EndDate.SetFocus
    If Txt_EndDate.Text = "" Then
        null_SetUp = True
    Else
        str_EndDate = Txt_EndDate
    End If
        
    If (null_SetUp = True) Then
        MsgBox "Controls not filled out"
    Else
        Str_SQL = "SELECT Tbl_Journal.Keyword, Tbl_Journal.Date_Time, Tbl_Journal.Journal_Entry, Tbl_Journal.ID "
        Str_SQL = Str_SQL & "FROM Tbl_Journal "
        'Str_SQL = Str_SQL & "WHERE (((Tbl_Journal.Keyword) = 'Daily Journal')) "
        'Str_SQL = Str_SQL & " And ((Tbl_Journal.Date_Time) > " & Str_StartDate & ") "
        'Str_SQL = Str_SQL & " And ((Tbl_Journal.Date_Time) <  " & str_EndDate & ")) "
        MsgBox Str_SQL
        
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL Str_SQL
        'DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query1"  This works but I want it to read the controls.
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
           
    End If
        
            
End Sub

The error message I am receiving is

A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SSQL statement.

I have played around with different configurations, and I am stumped.  I even commented out lines to shorten my SQL statement to troubleshoot what is going on.
My idea is to read up on the Recordset operation.
Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Can you show us the actual SQL statement as well?

You MUST have a WHERE before the AND is valid. Also, be extremely wary of using string concatenation like this. There's a thing called sql injection, and you should learn how to avoid it. It's one of those things that's too important to EVER do wrong, even for personal/practice/learning/proof of concept projects.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.runsql - RunSql only supports an action query or a data-definition query. A SELECT...FROM query is not allowed.

Try it with out your date filters. If it works I think you need either # or ‘ around your date strings.  Consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367098/vba-sql-access-db-query-date-statement

Or consider this approach https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5g1dTFKxiSg

Use # to delimit date/time values, apostrophe to delimit text values. > #" & Str_StartDate & "#) ". Your SQL excludes the end dates, is that what you want?

Michael Liu has already explained why you get that error with RunSql.  But what do you want to accomplish with your SELECT query, @MichaelBowen?  Do you want to view the data the query returns?  Or do you want to use it in a Recordset to do other stuff with it?

This question is similar to: Code to loop through all records in MS Access. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I wrote a form that allows the user to input a date range and a keyword (keyword through some vba code and displays the result in a form.  The problem with the form is that if I want to print it or save it to disc it isn't in a csv format.  So I want to write code that reads 3 controls (keyword, start date, end date, runs the query, and saves the result to a csv file.  Then I can open it in excel, or word, and print it.

I purchased an access /vba for dummies, and the example I wrote said it should work, then found out where it said it won't work for a select query like this.  It goes on to say that the way to do it is with a recordset.  It's getting there.

Did that book ever explain what to do with a recordset so the data could be exported? Because what you have so far doesn't export.

Not as of yet.  After the open command I can look at the recordset value and the row count is -1, which I take it means there is a syntax error.  Here is my code so far:

Here is the section of code:          Str_SQL = "SELECT Tbl_Journal.ID, Tbl_Journal.Keyword, Tbl_Journal.Date_Time, Tbl_Journal.Journal_Entry "
Str_SQL = Str_SQL & "FROM Tbl_Journal "
MsgBox Str_SQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False     'turn off warnings

    JrnlRecordSet.Open Str_SQL, , adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
    
    MsgBox JrnlRecordSet.RecordCount
    
    JrnlRecordSet.Close     'close recordset
    cnnJrnl.Close           'Close connection
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True  'Turn warnings back on


Edit question to post code, not a comment. Set Warnings and RunSQL are irrelevant to a SELECT sql. And if you have a functioning SELECT and you want an accurate recordcount, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html#RecordCount_without_MoveLast

-1 for the recordcount is correct. however, consider dropping in a sub form as a table layout of some type, and send the SQL to that sub form for display. In other words, it really depends on what you want to do with the SQL results.  so the "-1" for recordcount is done for reasons of performance, and the recordset will not full fully untill you "use it", or do a .movelast

Based on the comments, it seems your goal is to use form controls to specify a set of data which you can export as a CSV file.
In that case, I suggest there is a simpler way to go about it.  Create a query which references your form controls and use DoCmd.TransferText to export the query.
Here is my simple query, Query1, which references just one form control, a combo box:
SELECT t1.ID, t1.some_text, t1.Date_Time
FROM tblOne AS t1
WHERE t1.some_text=Forms!Form1!cboTextKey;

Then in my form's Cmd_SaveToFile command button's click event procedure, I can check whether the combo contains a suitable value and export the query data if it does:
Private Sub Cmd_SaveToFile_Click()
    Const cstrQuery As String = "Query1"
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFullPath As String

    If Len(Nz(Me.cboTextKey.Value, vbNullString)) = 0 Then
        ' the combo value is either Null or an empty string
        MsgBox "Control not filled out"
    Else
        ' the output CSV file will be in the same folder as the current
        ' database; and the file name will be the query name plus ".csv";
        strFolder = CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92)
        strFullPath = strFolder & cstrQuery & ".csv"
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , cstrQuery, strFullPath, True
    End If
End Sub

So you would need to expand that example to deal with 3 form controls and maybe change the file name and location logic.  But still I don't see any need to bother with a Recordset or to create or modify an SQL statement every time you run your code.  Just create a named query and export it.
BTW, if you really just want to print the data set, perhaps you needn't even bother with CSV.  Instead consider an Access report based on the query.

The Access report doesn't format the answer the way I want.  My reading in the Access/VBA for dummies book suggested I can read the form values and export it that way.

By its title, the book sounds like it favors VBA for most Access solutions. But as this answer shows, saved Access SQL queries can directly read values from open forms. Please advise how this solution does not render your desired CSV results.
